# Grouping negative and positive counts in a list

Tags: python, count

I have a list of numbers that contain positive, negative and zero numbers.
My goal is to count the group of positive neighbouring numbers including zero if exists. And will do same thing to the negative numbers.

Here is an example.

```
 a = [0-1,-2,-3,4,5,-6,-7,-8,-9,10,0,11,10,-1,-2,0]
```

expected out come

[3 (negative),2 (positive),4 (negative),4(positive including zero),3 (negative including zero)]

I tried the following code so far:

```py
a = [0-1,-2,-3,4,5,-6,-7,-8,-9,10,0,11,10,-1,-2,0]

  count_p  = 0 
  count_n  = 0


  group_count = []  

  for i in range(len(a)):

    
    if ((a[i] == 0 or a[i+1] == 0) or (a[i]>0 and a[i+1] >0)):
        
        count_p = count_p + 1
        
        group_count.append(count_p)
        

    elif ((a[i] == 0 or a[i+1] == 0) or (a[i]<0 and a[i+1] <0)):
        
        count_n = count_n + 1
        
        group_count.append(count_n)
```

Comment: Do you know how to use `if else` and `for` loop? This can be done even without any external libary,

Comment: What have you tried, why did it fail?

Comment: So far, I tried the following code but stuck                                                          { {   a = [0-1,-2,-3,4,5,-6,-7,-8,-9,10,0,11,10,-1,-2,0]

count_p  = 0 
count_n  = 0

for val in a:
    
    if val == 0 or val>0:
        
        count_p = count_p + 1
        
        print(count_p)
        
    else:
        
        count_n = count_n + 1
        
       # print(count_n)  }

Comment: I am sorry, I donot know how to post python codes here.

Comment: You don't post them here, you edit your question with relevant information

Answer (score -1):

```py
a = [0,-1,-2,-3,4,5,-6,-7,-8,-9,10,0,11,10,-1,-2,0]

pos=0
neg=0

for A in a:
    if A<0:
        neg+=1
    else:
        pos+=1

print(pos,neg)
```

Comment: Thank you @Tasnim013, but my goal is to group the adjacent positive numbers including zero if exists and same thing for negative numbers.